# Weird behaviour of the msxml .dll's

Tags: vb6, msxml, dll

All of a sudden some of our clients experience the ActiveX component can't create object error when the program tries to instantiate a MSXML2.DOMDocument. We are talking about a VB6 app here that is written on a computer that sets a reference to msxml2.dll and no other xml-dll. When we issue a deployment we deploy msxml2.dll msxml2a.dll and msxml2r.dll every time and have never had any issues.

Not this time! It is as if the windows environment itself has changed and rejects the unregistering/reregistering process. 
Whatever I do I am unable to get the client computer to succesfully instantiate the MSXML2.DOMDocument. 
To make things even more strange: When I rename/unregister/delete all msxml2* files from the system32 folder, clients that do not experience the problem keep functioning, so they do not seem to need the .dll's! Usually this clients will have a mix of msxml3, 4 and 6 installed. I searched the hard drive and there are no other copies of msxml2 lurking around.

Can someone please help to get a start of a grip on this baffling problem?

EDIT: just a simple set doc=new MSXML2.DOMDocument is enough to cause the error.

Comment: Do you have a more specific error about when the object cannot be created? Then next step would be the registry; Go find the MSXML2.DOMDocument class and follow it to it's implementation class. That should show you which .dll is being used for the object you are using. when you register a COM object (like MSXML) its just writing info to the registry. With a 'regsvr32 MSXML2.DLL' command you would reset the registry values to use that .dll you just 'registered'. Does you installer "regsvr32" the delivered msxml2.dll(s) ?

Comment: @ Marvin Smit: we use Inno Setup and yes it has unregistered and reregistered the .dll's for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of libraries are system-managed now.  Dumping things into System32 only gets you so far, since the "real" libraries live in the SxS Cache.

This is one reason why you want to use an approved deployment technique for them, and for MSXML this gets a little complicated unless you simply use the prescribed MSI packages (or those wrapped in an EXE) from Microsoft.  MSXML 4 was also available in MSM and CAB formats for each update, which had more to do with the "SxS install" that was only supported for MSXML 4 (dropped as a bad idea in MSXML 6).

The good news is that all supported OSs except Server 2003 already include MSXML 6, so target that and you're home free with no deployment requirement:

[MSXML6 is now in-band, MSI setup headaches should now (almost) be gone..](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2010/07/02/msxml6-is-now-in-band-msi-setup-headaches-should-now-almost-be-gone.aspx)

MSXML 3 is available on most Windows versions going back further, and can be deployed back to at least Win98: [Microsoft XML Parser (MSXML) 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28494391-052b-42ff-9674-f752bdca9582)

Installation and component registration and servicing hasn't worked as you might think it does for a long time now.  It is much safer to package your applications as MSI packages rather than using legacy scripted setup tools.  Don't try to deploy bits and pieces of complex packages like MDAC and MSXML.

Which specific MSXML version are you doing early binding to?  Keep in mind that if you use MSXML 4 this is sub-version specific (not all interfaces were binary compatible from service pack to service pack).

Comment: We early bind to msxml2, but I compiled versions that reference 4. I will try to go to 6.

Comment: MSXML2 isn't a version anymore so much as an interface spec. In the "References" dialog MSXML appears as "Microsoft XML, v3.0" etc.  If you use v4.0 you get the latest installed unless your application manifest selects one of the SxS-installed SP levels (i.e. there can be multiple v4.0's on a machine).

Comment: Referencing msxml6 and renaming all MSXML2.DOMDocument references to MSXML2.DOMDocument60 did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to always use version dependent ProgIDs instead of version independent ones. For example, I would suggest you to use Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 instead. Please refer to [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) for more information.

Comment: But in this case he wasn't using late binding, so ProgID values aren't relevant. I see he did choose to use particular version-dependent interfaces, which works but isn't normally necessary unless you're using version-specific features.